# ¿Cómo evitar que la segunda palabra de cada < li > pase hacia abajo?

Tags: html, css

Resulta que tengo este `nav`:

```css
.insidenav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
.firstnav{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.alaizq{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.aladcha{
    margin-left: 35%;
}
.aladcha2{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navonlyinfull">
        <div class="insidenav">
            <div class="firstnav">
                <li class="margin-check alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Buscar empleos</a></li>
                <li class="alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Valoraciones de empresa</a></li>
                <li class="alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Buscar candidatos</a></li>
                <li class="alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Empresas/Publicar empleos</a></li>
                <li class="aladcha" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Publica tu CV</a></li>
                <li class="aladcha2" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Pues tengo el problema de que cuando me pongo a estrechar la anchura de la pantalla, **aunque en la `nav` todavía hay espacio de sobra** los `< li >` se rompen hacia la siguiente linea. Me explico: Por ejemplo en "Empresas/Publicar empleos", Publicar empleos baja hacia la siguiente linea, como si se hubiese agotado el espacio de la `navbar` y entonces el programa debe bajar la segunda palabra hacia abajo para que todo entre bien sin reducir el `fontsize`. Sin embargo si hay espacio.

He probado a dividir y hacer dos `divs` diferentes. Uno para los `li` donde tengo puesto la clase "`alaizq`" y otro `div` para los `li` que tengo la clase "`aladcha`". Incluso poniendo una anchura muy grande en ambos `div`, me sigo ocurriendo el mismo problema.

Comment: Prueba poniendoles un `display: inline-block`

Comment: Tienes varios errores, entre ellos uno bastante importante que es el tener <li> cuyo padre no sea un <ul> un <ol> o un <menu>. Esto hará que su comportamiento sea erroneo, no pudiendo darles, por ejemplo, un width en píxeles fijo, que es justo lo que necesitas.

Comment: A parte de lo que PHPMyguel ha dicho, cosa que es bastante importante, el problema viene a raíz del margen en porcentaje que tiene el `li` con clase `aladcha`. Si inspeccionas el código en cualquier navegador, ese margen está ocupando todo el hueco que parece sobrar entre ambos bloques y, por lo tanto, no hay suficiente como para que el texto de cada `li` se muestre entero en una única línea. Te aconsejaría separarlos en dos bloques y trabajar con ellos por separado.

Answer (score 0):

Algo así quieres, solo sirve en `pantalla completa` por que en pantallas menores no hay forma de que no se corte

```css
.insidenav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
.firstnav{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.firstnav li{flex: 1 1 auto;}
.alaizq{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.aladcha{
    margin-left: 35%;
}
.aladcha2{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navonlyinfull">
        <div class="insidenav">
            <div class="firstnav">
                <li class="margin-check alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Buscar empleos</a></li>
                <li class="alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Valoraciones de empresa</a></li>
                <li class="alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Buscar candidatos</a></li>
                <li class="alaizq" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Empresas/Publicar empleos</a></li>
                <li class="aladcha" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Publica tu CV</a></li>
                <li class="aladcha2" style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Por supuesto que hay formas de que no se corte. Para eso existen las MediaQueries.

Comment: Si claro pero en este ejemplo no es posible, según como esta la estructura

Comment: Claro que es posible, qué es lo que lo impide? Solamente tiene que añadir @media a su CSS con las especificaciones.